# 502 error response from API Gateway in react but works on postman

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, post, postman, aws-api-gateway

When I send a request to my API on API Gateway either through the testing bit, or through POSTMAN, the request is sent and received okay, and I can the expected response body, however, when I make the API request through the code below, I get a 502 error.

There are no issues with the CORS policies as I am not getting any of those errors, here is my request code and the subsequent errors.

**POST REQUEST CODE**

```
fetch('https://4diopo9a77.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/DSA_API/imagedata', {
    method: 'POST',
    body :"{'A':'A'}"
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
})
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT**

```
POST `API_NAME` 502
Response {type: 'cors', url: '*API_NAME*', redirected: false, status: 502, ok: false, …}
```

**ERROR 1 STACK TRACE**

```
POSTRequest @   Home.js:15
getFileData @   Home.js:49
callCallback    @   react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev    @   react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback   @   react-dom.development.js:4056
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @   react-dom.development.js:4070
executeDispatch @   react-dom.development.js:8243
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder    @   react-dom.development.js:8275
processDispatchQueue    @   react-dom.development.js:8288
dispatchEventsForPlugins    @   react-dom.development.js:8299
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:8508
batchedEventUpdates$1   @   react-dom.development.js:22396
batchedEventUpdates @   react-dom.development.js:3745
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem   @   react-dom.development.js:8507
attemptToDispatchEvent  @   react-dom.development.js:6005
dispatchEvent   @   react-dom.development.js:5924
unstable_runWithPriority    @   scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1   @   react-dom.development.js:11276
discreteUpdates$1   @   react-dom.development.js:22413
discreteUpdates @   react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent   @   react-dom.development.js:5889
```

**ERROR 2 DETAILS**

```
body: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 502
statusText: ""
type: "cors"
url: "*API_NAME*"
[[Prototype]]: Response
```

[Here is an image of the POSTMAN request info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCqPg.png)

Comment: How about including your Postman details so we can compare what works and what doesn't work? There's obviously a difference there.

Comment: @MarkB Added an image of them!

Comment: @MarkB, the error is 502 Internal server error, i don't know if that helps

Comment: 502 Internal Server Error means you need to go look at your backend logs to see what the **actual** error is.

Comment: Your Postman screenshot only shows the headers you have configured. It doesn't show the request body.

Comment: @MarkB My api gateway is connected to lambda functions, but when I look at the cloudwatch logs it doesn't show any errors

Comment: @MarkB the postman request body is "{'A': 'A'}"

Comment: If the error is occurring in API Gateway, you may need to [enable API Gateway Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html) first, then check the error in that log.

Comment: @MarkB, the data is in the lambda function, I can see it in my cloudwatch now, but I am now getting cors errors when i try and return json.loads(event['body']) in the response body

Comment: So you found the error and fixed it? If you aren't going to include the error message in this question, or give any details on how you fixed it, then you should probably just delete this question since it won't be of use to anybody in the future. If you can't figure out the CORS error then post a new question on that, although you probably just need to go into API Gateway and enable CORS.

Comment: @MarkB, I have made a new post, okay if you have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Cors headings needed to be added to the response, the browser was blocking the response as it wasn't returning the heading, added this and it worked:

`"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*'`

So my return in the lambda looked like this:

```
return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(data),
        "headers": {
            'Content-Type': 'application/JSON',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*'
        },
    }
```

Comment: const Cors = require('koa2-cors');
const app = new Koa();
app.use(Cors());